# How to plot data from scope that is used in external mode simulation?

Tags: matlab, logging, scope, simulink

I have a simulink model connected to my hardware and I am able to see the response on my scope when I change the setpoints in my model etc. But I will like to save this data from the scope so that later I can plot it.

I have read some documentation online but I am still confused. Can someone give me a step by step method on how to plot this data from the scope used in external mode.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a [write data to workspace](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) block in simulink. You can put that block in the same bus as the scope and save the data to Matlab. If you want it automatically save into the disk, then I recommend to write a small `.m` script that takes this variable and saves in disk using [`save()`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html). You can automatically run this `.m` file after the Simulink model is stopped (or some other condition you prefer) going to `Properties->Callbacks` and choosing the appropriate function callback.